# Why does Visual Studio 2012 open a browser window to the address 0.0.0.1?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

When debugging web applications, VS2012 is opening two browser windows. One to my application and another to 0.0.0.1.

Any clue as to why and how I can stop it. It's pretty annoying having to close that window every time I debug.